# How to get the value of JTextField in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I have a JTextField and a JButton. I'm trying to get what user types in the textfield when they click the button.

```
public String insideTextField;

public void login() {

    loginFrame = new JFrame("Test");
    loginFrame.setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());
    loginFrame.setSize(400,400);
    loginFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(12, 3));

    loginFrame.add(usernameField);
    loginFrame.add(loginButton);

    loginButton.addActionListener(e -> {

        insideTextField = usernameField.getText();
        loginFrame.setVisible(false);
    });

    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and I expect the `insideTextField` to be what user types in the text field after I called this method. but it is null. However, the `loginFrame` will be hidden because of `loginFrame.setVisible(false);` so the button is working !

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, and *showing* the problem: the code you posted never does anything with insideTextField

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations involve magical thinking. Understand that `insideTextField` holds a String object, an object which in fact is *immutable* (cannot be changed). Yes, when you create the `insideTextField` you assign to it the String that just so happens to be residing within the JTextField, likely an empty `""` String, but understand that when the JTextField's text properties change, the `insideTextField` will not, and in fact *cannot* magically change on its own. The solution is to **not** have a `insideTextField` field, and instead give the class a getter method that extracts the current String within the JTextField when it is needed. For example:

```
public String getUserName() {
    return usernameField.getText();
}
```

Side note: I usually use a modal JDialog and *not* a JFrame to get log-in credentials. This way since the dialog is modal, I know when the user is done using it.  And in fact a JOptionPane works as a quick and dirty modal dialog creator. For example if we had a login JPanel like so:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private JTextField usernameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

    public LoginPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = getGbc(0, 0);
        add(new JLabel("User Name:"), gbc);
        gbc = getGbc(1, 0);
        add(usernameField, gbc);
        gbc = getGbc(0, 1);
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);
        gbc = getGbc(1, 1);
        add(passwordField, gbc);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
    }

    private static GridBagConstraints getGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        gbc.anchor = x == 0 ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;        

        return gbc;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return usernameField.getText();
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordField.getPassword();
    }
}
```

again one that uses getter methods to extract the text in the JTextField, we could display it in a JOptionPane like so:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("LoginExample");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// fill the JFrame with the main GUI
// .... 

frame.pack();

// create the LoginPanel JPanel here
LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel();

// and display it in a JOptionPane here
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, loginPanel, 
        "User Log-In", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    String userName = loginPanel.getUserName();
    char[] password = loginPanel.getPassword();

    // test to make sure code is working
    System.out.println("User Name: " + userName);

    // check for name/password validity here
    // ... if name/password OK, then show JFrame:
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```